# No image exist, load default image - do errors slow things?

Tags: image, load, default

**INTRO**

I have inventory mysql db I pull inventory records from with images. In most cases there is no image for the item so i use the following script to determine if a image exist and if not use a default image.

**PROBLEM**

Default img takes a while to load when the query results are 100 or more, i.e. 1500. I think this has more to do processing img errors vs loading the same default images. Maybe its processing time looking up all the images(I am inclined to believe it is both). NOTE - If I DO NOT include images - the text results load quickly.

**Potential Solution**

- Page pagination - I prefer another work around
- Disable img error reporting - Can I do this with jquery? or is this has to be done in php.
- Use a script that does not require as much processing for the image. i.e looking up all the images at once ? - Maybe lazyload jquery plugin would solve this problem. FYI - My query results are displayed in an iframe.

**SCRIPT I CURRENT USE**

```
<div class='iimgd radius5'>
<img class='iimg radius5' src='../images/".$results['Description'].".jpg' onerror=\"this.src='../images/default.jpg'\"></div>
```

.

**ANY THOUGHTS ARE APPRECIATED**